# Getting an "AttributeError: module 'pandas' has no attribute 'plotting'" when trying to use Folium

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas

I am trying to learn and use folium in Python, but when I run my code:

```
import folium
map = folium.Map(location=[80, -100])
map.save("Map1.html")
```

I get an error saying:

```
(venv) C:\Users\kkham\PycharmProjects\PythonMegaCourse\Mapping>python app2.py
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "app2.py", line 1, in <module>
    import folium
  File "C:\Users\kkham\PycharmProjects\PythonMegaCourse\venv\lib\site-packages\folium\__init__.py", line 20, in <module>
    from folium.features import (
  File "C:\Users\kkham\PycharmProjects\PythonMegaCourse\venv\lib\site-packages\folium\features.py", line 17, in <module>
    from folium.folium import Map
  File "C:\Users\kkham\PycharmProjects\PythonMegaCourse\venv\lib\site-packages\folium\folium.py", line 13, in <module>
    from folium.map import FitBounds
  File "C:\Users\kkham\PycharmProjects\PythonMegaCourse\venv\lib\site-packages\folium\map.py", line 14, in <module>
    from folium.utilities import validate_location, camelize, parse_options
  File "C:\Users\kkham\PycharmProjects\PythonMegaCourse\venv\lib\site-packages\folium\utilities.py", line 17, in <module>
    import pandas as pd
  File "C:\Users\kkham\PycharmProjects\PythonMegaCourse\venv\lib\site-packages\pandas\__init__.py", line 55, in <module>
    from pandas.core.api import (
  File "C:\Users\kkham\PycharmProjects\PythonMegaCourse\venv\lib\site-packages\pandas\core\api.py", line 29, in <module>
    from pandas.core.groupby import Grouper, NamedAgg
  File "C:\Users\kkham\PycharmProjects\PythonMegaCourse\venv\lib\site-packages\pandas\core\groupby\__init__.py", line 1, in <module>
    from pandas.core.groupby.generic import DataFrameGroupBy, NamedAgg, SeriesGroupBy
  File "C:\Users\kkham\PycharmProjects\PythonMegaCourse\venv\lib\site-packages\pandas\core\groupby\generic.py", line 60, in <module>
    from pandas.core.frame import DataFrame
  File "C:\Users\kkham\PycharmProjects\PythonMegaCourse\venv\lib\site-packages\pandas\core\frame.py", line 124, in <module>
    from pandas.core.series import Series
  File "C:\Users\kkham\PycharmProjects\PythonMegaCourse\venv\lib\site-packages\pandas\core\series.py", line 122, in <module>
    class Series(base.IndexOpsMixin, generic.NDFrame):
  File "C:\Users\kkham\PycharmProjects\PythonMegaCourse\venv\lib\site-packages\pandas\core\series.py", line 4562, in Series
    plot = CachedAccessor("plot", pandas.plotting.PlotAccessor)
AttributeError: module 'pandas' has no attribute 'plotting'
```

Not sure why or how to fix this problem. I also was searching around and some forum mentioned something about Anaconda and PyQt4 but not sure how that would be relevant if I'm using PyCharm. I have folium, plotting, and pandas all successfully installed.

Comment: What version of pandas is installed in the python env configured in pycharm to execute the code? Also just run  `from pandas.plotting import PlotAccessor` to see if it will raise an error. It does not in pandas `1.0.1`

Comment: @Chris I went to my terminal in PyCharm and ran the code you told me to and it does raise an error `ImportError: DLL load failed: %1 is not a valid Win32 application.` I tried to see if I could just import pandas, but for some reason, I get the same error as well.